# How to calculate the product of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, products

How can you calculate the product of a set $A$, denoted by $\Pi A$ and defined by

$\forall z \in \Pi A(z \subseteq \bigcup A \wedge \forall y \in A (\exists x (z \cap y = \lbrace x \rbrace)))  $

Also, is it different for finite and infinite sets?

Comment: I'm not sure that definition works for the standard definition of product of sets that I've seen.

Comment: I'd like to know that definition, can you provide some links or documents with it? Just in case notice that I'm not speaking about Cartesian product but internal product of a set, sometimes it's defined as the set of all functions.

Comment: I don't know the standard definition, only that your definition has problems dealing with sets with common elements. If $A=\{\{1,2,3\},\{1,2,4\}\}$, it only allows $\{1\},\{2\},\{3,4\}$.

Comment: I was confident mine was the standard definition, if someone knows it please edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

If the sets in $A$ are not pairwise disjoint, then the product you define can be empty. This is not a standard situation, and certainly this definition (in general) is not the standard definition.

To see why this might be the case consider $A=\{\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\}\}$, and you will see that there are no $z$ satisfying this definition.

The standard definition for the product of sets (we don't require them to be disjoint) is to say that $f\in\prod A$ is a function with domain $A$, and $f(a)\in a$ for all $a\in A$. So if $A$ is a collection of pairwise disjoint sets, then this is easily equivalent, simply take the range of $f$ to be $z$ as in your definition, and take $f(a)$ to be the unique $x$ such that $x\in z\cap a$.

As to how you calculate such a set (assuming that you require $A$ to be a set of pairwise disjoint sets)? You just go over all the possible sets which satisfy the definition, there's really no concrete algorithm. In the case of an infinite $A$, you need the axiom of choice to ensure that it isn't empty, and the result is an infinite set which is usually "very large".

Comment: Can you please edit my question so it reflects the standard definition? I wasn't thinking about other definitions of product.

Comment: Then I really don't understand your question.

Comment: It's how you calculate the standard definition of product, but it seems the one I'm using is not standard.

Comment: There's really nothing to "calculate", it's a set defined by some formula. There's nothing to it.